# Reduce the size of Keras LSTM model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

Essentially, I am training an LSTM model using Keras, but when I save it, its size takes up to 100MB. However, my purpose of the model is to deploy to a web server in order to serve as an API, my web server is not able to run it since the model size is too big. After analyzing all parameters in my model, I figured out that my model has `20,000,000` parameters but `15,000,000` parameters are untrained since they are word embeddings. Is there any way that I can minimize the size of the model by removing that `15,000,000` parameters but still preserving the performance of the model?
Here is my code for the model:

```
def LSTModel(input_shape, word_to_vec_map, word_to_index):


    sentence_indices = Input(input_shape, dtype="int32")

    embedding_layer = pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map, word_to_index)


    embeddings = embedding_layer(sentence_indices)


    X = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True)(embeddings)
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
    X = LSTM(256, return_sequences=False)(X)
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)    
    X = Dense(NUM_OF_LABELS)(X)
    X = Activation("softmax")(X)

    model = Model(inputs=sentence_indices, outputs=X)

    return model
```

Comment: In addition to it, I would recommend you to post it on Keras's Slack group as well. Its a big network dedicated for Slack (doesn't mean answer won't be found here, but no harm in posting there too).

Comment: Wow i don't even realize it exists. Thanks for that

Comment: Welcome! Please join it: https://kerasteam.slack.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the layers you want to save outside the function and name them. Then create two functions `foo()` and `bar()`. `foo()` will have the original pipeline including the embedding layer. `bar()` will have only the part of pipeline AFTER embedding layer. Instead, you will define new `Input()` layer in `bar()` with dimensions of your embeddings:

```
lstm1 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, name='lstm1')
lstm2 = LSTM(256, return_sequences=False, name='lstm2')
dense = Dense(NUM_OF_LABELS, name='Susie Dense')

def foo(...):
    sentence_indices = Input(input_shape, dtype="int32")
    embedding_layer = pretrained_embedding_layer(word_to_vec_map, word_to_index)
    embeddings = embedding_layer(sentence_indices)
    X = lstm1(embeddings)
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
    X = lstm2(X)
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)    
    X = dense(X)
    X = Activation("softmax")(X)
    return Model(inputs=sentence_indices, outputs=X)


def bar(...):
    embeddings = Input(embedding_shape, dtype="float32")
    X = lstm1(embeddings)
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)
    X = lstm2(X)
    X = Dropout(0.5)(X)    
    X = dense(X)
    X = Activation("softmax")(X)
    return Model(inputs=sentence_indices, outputs=X)

foo_model = foo(...)
bar_model = bar(...)

foo_model.fit(...)
bar_model.save_weights(...)
```

Now, you will train the original `foo()` model. Then you can save the weights of the reduced `bar()` model. When loading the model, don't forget to specify `by_name=True` parameter:

```
foo_model.load_weights('bar_model.h5', by_name=True)
```

Comment: If we trained `foo(...)`, how will `bar_model.save_weights(...)` save the trained weights? Just trying to understand.

Comment: @manic.coder The layers lstm1, lstm2 and dense are created outside the function and then simply reused in both functions. Effectively, sharing weights. Thus, changes to weights made by training foo_model automatically reflects in the bar_model.